# Execute a simple java code in Intellij-Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Can you help me to run the code? I am trying to execute the following:

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello,world!");
    }
}
```

To do that I click Run->Run (the second one with Alt+Shift+F10). It outputs a small window where the only available option is Edit configurations, I tried to do that but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While editing your first configuration.

Clik `+` button and choose `Application` template

[image]

In Main class: type `HelloWorld` or pick it from the picker `...`

Comment: If there is no such class in the picker … should I create it somehow? Right now it prints a Warning: Class "HelloWorld" is not found in module "My_Own_Project.java"

Comment: You should have a file in your project tree under `src` folder called `HelloWorld.jave` where there is the code you have posted.

Comment: So all I need to do is to change my project name from "My_Own_Project.java" to "HelloWorld.java"?

Comment: Yep, if you have a public class called HelloWorld, it must be inside a file named the same.